# Table View in FlexBox

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I'm trying to get a view where I stack 3 Columns however I'm not able to get it with FlexBox, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is how it looks currently:

[image: Image how it is looking]

This is my code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import Colors from '../constants/Colors';
import FormButton from '../components/UI/FormButton';

const InfoEntradas = props => {

    const [entradaSol, setEntradaSol] = useState();
    const [precioSol, setPrecioSol] = useState();
    const [entradaPrefNorte, setEntradaPrefNorte] = useState();
    const [precioPrefNorte, setPrecioPrefNorte] = useState();
    const [entradaSombraNorte, setEntradaSombraNorte] = useState();
    const [precioSombraNorte, setPrecioSombraNorte] = useState();
    const [entradaTribunaNorte, setEntradaTribunaNorte] = useState();
    const [precioTribunaNorte, setPrecioTribunaNorte] = useState();
    const [entradaPlatea, setEntradaPlatea] = useState();
    const [precioPlatea, setPrecioPlatea] = useState();
    const [entradaTribunaSur, setEntradaTribunaSur] = useState();
    const [precioTribunaSur, setPrecioTribunaSur] = useState();
    const [entradaSombraSur, setEntradaSombraSur] = useState();
    const [precioSombraSur, setPrecioSombraSur] = useState();
    const [entradaPrefSur, setEntradaPrefSur] = useState();
    const [precioPrefSur, setPrecioPrefSur] = useState();

    return (
        <View style={styles.centered}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Entradas por Localidad vs {props.route.params.rival}</Text>
            <View
                style={{
                    borderBottomColor: 'Black',
                    borderBottomWidth: 5,
                }}
            />
            <View style={styles.row}>
                <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Localidad</Text>
                <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Cantidad Entradas</Text>
                <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Precio</Text>
            </View>
            <ScrollView style={{ alignContent: 'center' }}>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Text style={styles.localidad}>Sol General</Text>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        onChangeText={(value) => {setEntradaSol(value)}}
                        placeholder = 'Entradas'
                        value={entradaSol}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        onChangeText={(value) => { setPrecioSol(value)}}
                        placeholder = 'Precio'
                        value={precioSol}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Text style={styles.localidad}>Preferente Norte</Text>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        onChangeText={(value) => {setEntradaPrefNorte(value)}}
                        placeholder = 'Entradas'
                        value={entradaPrefNorte}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        onChangeText={(value) => {setPrecioPrefNorte(value)}}
                        placeholder = 'Precio'
                        value={precioPrefNorte}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Text style={styles.localidad}>Sombra Norte</Text>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        onChangeText={(value) => {setEntradaSombraNorte(value)}}
                        placeholder = 'Entradas'
                        value={entradaSombraNorte}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        onChangeText={(value) => {setPrecioSombraNorte(value)}}
                        placeholder = 'Precio'
                        value={precioSombraNorte}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Text style={styles.localidad}>Tribuna Norte</Text>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        onChangeText={(value) => {setEntradaTribunaNorte(value)}}
                        placeholder = 'Entradas'
                        value={entradaTribunaNorte}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        onChangeText={(value) => {setPrecioTribunaNorte(value)}}
                        placeholder = 'Precio'
                        value={precioTribunaNorte}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Text style={styles.localidad}>Platea</Text>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        onChangeText={(value) => {setEntradaPlatea(value)}}
                        placeholder = 'Entradas'
                        value={entradaPlatea}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        onChangeText={(value) => {setPrecioPlatea(value)}}
                        placeholder = 'Precio'
                        value={precioPlatea}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Text style={styles.localidad}>Tribuna Sur</Text>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        onChangeText={(value) => {setEntradaTribunaSur(value)}}
                        placeholder = 'Entradas'
                        value={entradaTribunaSur}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        onChangeText={(value) => {setPrecioTribunaSur(value)}}
                        placeholder = 'Precio'
                        value={precioTribunaSur}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Text style={styles.localidad}>Sombra Sur</Text>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        onChangeText={(value) => {setEntradaSombraSur(value)}}
                        placeholder = 'Entradas'
                        value={entradaSombraSur}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        onChangeText={(value) => {setPrecioSombraSur(value)}}
                        placeholder = 'Precio'
                        value={precioSombraSur}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Text style={styles.localidad}>Preferente Sur</Text>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        onChangeText={(value) => {setEntradaPrefSur(value)}}
                        placeholder = 'Entradas'
                        value={entradaPrefSur}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        onChangeText={(value) => {setPrecioPrefSur(value)}}
                        placeholder = 'Precio'
                        value={precioPrefSur}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.rowButton}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.button1}
                        onPress={() => {
                            console.log('Info Platea:');
                            console.log('Entradas: ' + entradaPlatea + ' Precio: $' + precioPlatea);
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Publicar</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.button2}
                        onPress={() => {
                            setEntradaSol('');
                            setPrecioSol('');
                            setEntradaPrefNorte('');
                            setPrecioPrefNorte('');
                            setEntradaSombraNorte('');
                            setPrecioSombraNorte('');
                            setEntradaTribunaNorte('');
                            setPrecioTribunaNorte('');
                            setEntradaPlatea('');
                            setPrecioPlatea('');
                            setEntradaTribunaSur('');
                            setPrecioTribunaSur('');
                            setEntradaSombraSur('');
                            setPrecioSombraSur('');
                            setEntradaPrefSur('');
                            setPrecioPrefSur('');
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Reset</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
};

export const screenOptions = navData => {
    return {
        headerTitle: 'Entradas vs ' + navData.route.params.rival,
    }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    centered: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    title: {
        marginTop: 15,
        marginBottom: 5,
        fontSize: 20,
        color: Colors.secondary,
        alignContent: 'center',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    row: {
        marginTop: 10,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        //flex: 1,
    },
    rowButton: {
        marginTop: 10,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',        
    },
    subtitle: {
        marginTop: 5,
        marginBottom: 5,
        marginHorizontal: 10,
        fontSize: 18,
        color: 'black',
        alignContent: 'center',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    localidad: {
        marginTop: 5,
        marginBottom: 5,
        marginHorizontal: 10,
        fontSize: 18,
        color: Colors.primary,
        alignContent: 'center',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    inputStyle: {
        height: 30,
        width: 100,
        borderColor: 'gray',
        borderWidth: 1,
        marginTop: 5,
        marginBottom: 5,
        marginHorizontal: 10,
        alignContent: 'center',
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
    button1: {
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#46A72E",
        padding: 10,
        marginHorizontal: 15,
        marginVertical: 15,
        height: 40,
        width: 150,
    },
    button2: {
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#BC281C",
        padding: 10,
        marginHorizontal: 15,
        marginVertical: 15,
        height: 40,
        width: 150,
    },
    buttonText:{
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
});

export default InfoEntradas;
```

My issue is mostly that it doesn't align all the inputs or labels in a column. I wish it could be all aligned so it doesn't look like this depending on the size of the label.

Any ideas on how I can order the view in three columns?

Comment: I would consider using Grid for this layout, is there any particular reason why you want to use Flexbox?

Comment: To get 3 equal columns with flexbox, just set `flex: 0 0 33.333%;` on each flex item (the immediate children of the container with display flex set). That `flex` property is short-hand for flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis ... so 0 0 33% means no shrink or grow and set to 33% width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the working solution: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/tenacious-soylent)**

[image]

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

const InfoEntradas = (props) => {
  const [entradaSol, setEntradaSol] = useState();
  const [precioSol, setPrecioSol] = useState();
  const [entradaPrefNorte, setEntradaPrefNorte] = useState();
  const [precioPrefNorte, setPrecioPrefNorte] = useState();
  const [entradaSombraNorte, setEntradaSombraNorte] = useState();
  const [precioSombraNorte, setPrecioSombraNorte] = useState();
  const [entradaTribunaNorte, setEntradaTribunaNorte] = useState();
  const [precioTribunaNorte, setPrecioTribunaNorte] = useState();
  const [entradaPlatea, setEntradaPlatea] = useState();
  const [precioPlatea, setPrecioPlatea] = useState();
  const [entradaTribunaSur, setEntradaTribunaSur] = useState();
  const [precioTribunaSur, setPrecioTribunaSur] = useState();
  const [entradaSombraSur, setEntradaSombraSur] = useState();
  const [precioSombraSur, setPrecioSombraSur] = useState();
  const [entradaPrefSur, setEntradaPrefSur] = useState();
  const [precioPrefSur, setPrecioPrefSur] = useState();

  return (
    <View style={styles.centered}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Entradas por Localidad vs </Text>
      <View
        style={{
          borderBottomColor: 'Black',
          borderBottomWidth: 5,
        }}
      />
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Localidad</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Cantidad Entradas</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Precio</Text>
      </View>
      <ScrollView style={{ alignContent: 'center' }}>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.localidad}>Sol General</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            onChangeText={(value) => {
              setEntradaSol(value);
            }}
            placeholder="Entradas"
            value={entradaSol}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            onChangeText={(value) => {
              setPrecioSol(value);
            }}
            placeholder="Precio"
            value={precioSol}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.localidad}>Preferente Norte</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            onChangeText={(value) => {
              setEntradaPrefNorte(value);
            }}
            placeholder="Entradas"
            value={entradaPrefNorte}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            onChangeText={(value) => {
              setPrecioPrefNorte(value);
            }}
            placeholder="Precio"
            value={precioPrefNorte}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.localidad}>Sombra Norte</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            onChangeText={(value) => {
              setEntradaSombraNorte(value);
            }}
            placeholder="Entradas"
            value={entradaSombraNorte}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            onChangeText={(value) => {
              setPrecioSombraNorte(value);
            }}
            placeholder="Precio"
            value={precioSombraNorte}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.localidad}>Tribuna Norte</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            onChangeText={(value) => {
              setEntradaTribunaNorte(value);
            }}
            placeholder="Entradas"
            value={entradaTribunaNorte}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            onChangeText={(value) => {
              setPrecioTribunaNorte(value);
            }}
            placeholder="Precio"
            value={precioTribunaNorte}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.localidad}>Platea</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            onChangeText={(value) => {
              setEntradaPlatea(value);
            }}
            placeholder="Entradas"
            value={entradaPlatea}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            onChangeText={(value) => {
              setPrecioPlatea(value);
            }}
            placeholder="Precio"
            value={precioPlatea}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.localidad}>Tribuna Sur</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            onChangeText={(value) => {
              setEntradaTribunaSur(value);
            }}
            placeholder="Entradas"
            value={entradaTribunaSur}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            onChangeText={(value) => {
              setPrecioTribunaSur(value);
            }}
            placeholder="Precio"
            value={precioTribunaSur}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.localidad}>Sombra Sur</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            onChangeText={(value) => {
              setEntradaSombraSur(value);
            }}
            placeholder="Entradas"
            value={entradaSombraSur}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            onChangeText={(value) => {
              setPrecioSombraSur(value);
            }}
            placeholder="Precio"
            value={precioSombraSur}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.localidad}>Preferente Sur</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            onChangeText={(value) => {
              setEntradaPrefSur(value);
            }}
            placeholder="Entradas"
            value={entradaPrefSur}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            onChangeText={(value) => {
              setPrecioPrefSur(value);
            }}
            placeholder="Precio"
            value={precioPrefSur}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.rowButton}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button1}
            onPress={() => {
              console.log('Info Platea:');
              console.log(
                'Entradas: ' + entradaPlatea + ' Precio: $' + precioPlatea
              );
            }}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Publicar</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button2}
            onPress={() => {
              setEntradaSol('');
              setPrecioSol('');
              setEntradaPrefNorte('');
              setPrecioPrefNorte('');
              setEntradaSombraNorte('');
              setPrecioSombraNorte('');
              setEntradaTribunaNorte('');
              setPrecioTribunaNorte('');
              setEntradaPlatea('');
              setPrecioPlatea('');
              setEntradaTribunaSur('');
              setPrecioTribunaSur('');
              setEntradaSombraSur('');
              setPrecioSombraSur('');
              setEntradaPrefSur('');
              setPrecioPrefSur('');
            }}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Reset</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

export const screenOptions = (navData) => {
  return {
    headerTitle: 'Entradas vs ' + navData.route.params.rival,
  };
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  centered: {
    marginTop: 30,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    marginTop: 15,
    marginBottom: 5,
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'blue',
    alignContent: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  row: {
    marginTop: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  rowButton: {
    marginTop: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  subtitle: {
    marginTop: 5,
    marginBottom: 5,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'black',
    alignContent: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  localidad: {
    marginTop: 5,
    marginBottom: 5,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'red',
    alignContent: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  inputStyle: {
    height: 30,
    flex: 1,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginTop: 5,
    marginBottom: 5,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    alignContent: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  button1: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#46A72E',
    padding: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 15,
    marginVertical: 15,
    height: 40,
    width: 150,
  },
  button2: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#BC281C',
    padding: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 15,
    marginVertical: 15,
    height: 40,
    width: 150,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

export default InfoEntradas;
```